# cohomology algebra of braid spaces, configuration spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

In *Homology of $C_{n+1}$-spaces, $n\geq 0$,* F.R. Cohen,  *Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 533,* Chapter 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, the cohomology algebra $H^*(B(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p),\mathbb{Z}_p)$, for $p$ prime and $B(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p)=F(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p)/\Sigma_p$, is obtained. A spectral sequence for fibration $\Sigma_p\to F(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p)\to B(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p)$ is used with the action of $\Sigma_p$ on $H^*(F(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p);\mathbb{Z})$.

For other manifolds $M$ such as $S^m$ and $S^m\times \mathbb{R}^k$ ($H^*F(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p;\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is known in these cases), are there any results for the cohomology algebra $H^*(B(M,p);\mathbb{Z}_p)$ in any references? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p=2$ there are references from which you can extract the $\mathbb{Z}/2$ cohomology algebra of $B(M,2)$ for any closed manifold $M$. The answer in principle depends only on $H^\ast(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ as a module over the Steenrod algebra, together with the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $M$, but is usually not very pleasant (even for manifolds with nice cohomology such as $\mathbb{R}P^n$). The method consists of showing that the map
$$
B(M,2)\to S^\infty \times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} M\times M
$$
is surjective in cohomology, and calculating its kernel.  The situation is nicely summarised in Section 4 of

Bausum, David R. *Embeddings and immersions of manifolds in Euclidean space.* 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 213 (1975), 263–303,

where you will find references to the original articles of Haefliger and Yo Ging-Tzung.

Answer (score 3):

The homology of configuration spaces of manifolds is completely calculated in Bödigheimer-Cohen-Taylor's "[On the homology of configuration spaces](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.nd.edu%2F~taylor%2Fpapers%2Fcocs.pdf&ei=CKG4VKneO4SzyASp0YGgDw&usg=AFQjCNGhxbMXXjDZaUT335FuM-iN65UXcQ&sig2=wDk_e8-lh2fp6f6N4iFfXQ&bvm=bv.83829542,d.aWw&cad=rja)" in *Topology*, at least at the prime 2, or at odd primes (or rationally) for odd dimensional manifolds.

Comment: Their methods do not give the product structure on cohomology, however.

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I missed that part of the question.