# characteristic classes of tangent bundle of 2-nd unordered configuration space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, chern-classes

Given a (real or almost complex) manifold $M$, Let the 2-nd unordered configuration space be the quotient space 
$$
B(M,2)=(M\times M\setminus\ \Delta)/\ \mathbb{Z}_2
$$
where
$$
\Delta=\{(m,m)\mid m\in M \}
$$
and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts by reversing the coordinates order. 
Then $B(M,2)$ is a (real or almost complex) manifold. Suppose the characteristic classes of $TM$ is given. How to obtain the characteristic classed of $TB(M,2)$? For example,

(1). How to compute the Stiefel-Whitney class
$$
w(TB(\mathbb{R}P^n,2))?
$$

(2). How to compute the Stiefel-Whitney class
$$
w(TB(\mathbb{C}P^n,2))?
$$

(2). How to compute the Chern class
$$
c(TB(\mathbb{C}P^n,2))?
$$

Comment: Don't we have the characteristic classes of $M\times M$ by the product formula? In which case, can't we simply pull-it back to $M\times M\setminus \Delta$?  Besides, why do you call this "symmetric product"? Usually symmetric product would mean $M\times M/(\Sigma _2)$, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, Prof. I type wrongly.

Comment: To answer this question you first need to describe the cohomology of the unordered configuration space. This can be done using the map $B(M,2)\to S^\infty\times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} M\times M$, as in my answer to your previous question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193982/cohomology-algebra-of-braid-spaces-configuration-spaces , but it's a bit messy. Then the next step would be to try to understand the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the quadratic construction on a vector bundle. This is an interesting question which should be approachable; I don't know if it's been done before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excellent discussion of symmetric powers in general is given by [Pavle Blagojevich](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/blag.pdf) - one of the first things he mentions is that the $k$-th symmetric power of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is $\mathbb{R}P^{kn},$ a result due to Arnold. This is NOT true of $\mathbb{C}P^n,$ but for $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ this is [studied by Gusein-Zade et al](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1562v2.pdf). This might be enough for what you want.(that paper seems quite nice also).

Comment: The question is not actually about symmetric powers (see user43326's comment)...